# Relativistic energy density of a fluid in different frames

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have a fluid in a local inertial frame with stress-energy tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$. In another local inertial frame that is moving with velocity $u$ with respect to the first one, it is said that the energy of a particle is
$$
E' = -c p\cdot u
$$
and therefore, the energy density is
$$
\epsilon' = \eta_{\mu\sigma} u^\sigma T^{\mu\nu} \eta_{\nu\rho} u^\rho
$$

I understand the basic meanings of the different components of the stress-energy tensor. However, I'm not able to see where those definitions for $E'$ and $\epsilon'$ come from. Any hint on this would be appreciated.